# What is the geometry of feasible region of vector program of MaxCut?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

The relaxation of MaxCut can be formed as a vector program:

$$ \text{maximize} \quad \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}v_i^Tv_j \qquad \text{subject to} \quad u_i \in \mathbb{R}^n,\quad \|u_i\|_{L^2}=1 $$

although we know that this is equivalent to SDP which feasible region is spectrahedron, I am wondering the geometry of

$$\left\{ \mathbf{u}=(u_1,\cdots,u_n)^T, \text{where each }u_i\in\mathbb{R}^n, \|u_i\|_{L^2}=1 \right\}$$

What does it look like? is it convex?

A follow-up question is:
does this two set equivalent?

$\{\mathbf{x}| \|x_i\|_{L_2}=1,\ \forall i\}$

$\{\mathbf{x}| \|x_i\|_{L_2}\leq 1,\ \forall i\}$

(a note: I added algebraic geometry tag here is because understanding high dimensional geometry such as spectrahedron is an direction in this subject.)

Comment: Start with $n=1$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo when $n=1$, $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,u_2)$ where $u_i$ is scalar. Then $\{\mathbf{u}|\|u_i\|_{L_2}=1\}$ contains only one element $(1,1)$, and this is a point.

Comment: If $n=1$ then the feasible space is $\pm 1$ which is not convex.

Comment: @copper.hat yes, thank you! and what is the geometry of this set in general?

Comment: That is a bit vague, it is a sphere.

Comment: @copper.hat ah if it's a sphere then it should be convex..

Comment: You need to do a little thinking.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't really know

Comment: It is the surface of a sphere which is not convex. draw a picture in the plane,

Comment: Where is the quadratic program?

Comment: so we have no tool to specify that the geometry of it is right?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by specifying the geometry.

Comment: @copper.hat like what is the class of geometry of it. for example linear matrix inequality gives spectrahedron

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the question is within the context of PSD cones.

We can think of $\textbf{x}$ corresponds to a PSD matrix $X$ with trace constraint. It is to see a bijective correspondence because if $X\succeq 0$, then $X = \textbf{x}^T\textbf{x}$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$, and the $X_{ii} = \textbf{x}^T_i\textbf{x}_i = |\textbf{x}_i|_{\ell_2}=1$. If we have two PSD matrices $X$ and $Y$ with the same trace constraint, their affine combination is still PSD with the same trace constraint. Therefore, $\textbf{x}$ defines a convex set in the PSD cone.

With the above interpretation, one would change the trace constraint from $X_{ii}=1$ to $X_{ii}\leq 1$. These are two different sets. However, under the optimization problem, the optima occur at the boundary of the constraint set, i.e., $X_{ii}==1$.